# Groupby with if parameter using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

My service have a enum parameter and I need group by parameter value

I'm currently using `if` and tried with `switch`

My navigation property have property `Name`

Using `if` or `Switch` I duplicate my code 
`Select(x =>`

My model:

```
public class Bill
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public Customer Customer {get;set;}

    public int BankAccountId {get;set;}
    public BankAccount BankAccount {get;set;}

    public int PlanId {get;set;}
    public Plan Plan {get;set;}

    public string Description {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
}
```

and my service return a DTO

```
public class BillService
{
     public BillDTO ReturnGroupBy(BillGroup group)
     {
            if (group== BillGroup.Customer)
            {
                return dbo.Bill.GroupBy(c => c.Customer).Select(c => new BillDTO { Nome = c.Nome })..
            }
            if(group== BillGroup.BankAccount)
            {
                return dbo.Bill.GroupBy(c => conta.BankAccount).Select(c => new BillDTO { Nome = c.Nome })..
            }

}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @haim770 how use if condition in groupby. Because I duplicate my select result

Comment: Just extract your projection into `Expression<Func<Bill, BillDTO>>` and use it in both `Select(...)`s

Comment: Both `Select` in the example (1) are invalid (2) are not the same because the source objects are of different types. The only reusable part (if any) could be after `Select`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the common denominator and declare a variable of that type, in this case `IQueryable<Bill>`:

```
IQueryable<Bill> groupedBills;

if (group == BillGroup.Customer)
{
    groupedBills = dbo.Bill.GroupBy(c => c.Customer);
}
else
{
    groupedBills = dbo.Bill.GroupBy(c => conta.BankAccount);
}

return groupedBills.Select(c => new BillDTO 
{ 
    Nome = c.Nome,
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the following class

```
public static class CustomQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<IGrouping<INamed, T>> GroupByNamed<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, BillGroup group)
    {
        //enum name must be the same as property name
        string property = group.ToString();

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        Expression prop = Expression.Property(parameter, property);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, INamed>>(prop, parameter);

        return query.GroupBy(lambda);
    }
}
```

With interface

```
public interface INamed
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this

```
var bills = context
    .Users
    .GroupByNamed(BillGroup.Customer)
    .Select(u => new BillDTO { Name = u.Key.Name });
```

Notice that in my example **User** class has to contain **Customer** property and this property has to implement the **INamed** interface.

So in your case your **Customer** and **BankAccount** classes have to implement the same interface containing **Nome** property to be able to use this extension like this

```
dbo
    .Bill
    .GroupByNamed(BillGroup.Customer)
    .Select(c => new BillDTO { Nome = c.Key.Nome })..
```